# textarea_name is not working with wp_editor

Tags: wp-editor

I used to use a normal textarea and tried to change the `wp_editor` on front-end.

```
<div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
    <textarea name="post_content" 
              rows="10" 
              cols="20" 
              placeholder="Briefly describe yourself. please do not put your email or phone number">
        <?php echo get_the_content($resume_id); ?>
    </textarea>
</div>
```

It works fine and I tried to change to `wp_editor`.

```
<?php

    $post      = get_post($resume_id, OBJECT, 'edit');
    $content   = $post->post_content;
    $editor_id = 'editpost';
    $settings  = array('textarea_name' => 'post_content');

    wp_editor($content, $editor_id, $settings );
?>
```

On next step, get the value like this.

```
$post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
```

when I use a normal textarea, it works fine, but It's not working with wp-editor. I have tried on Edit page, the value gets not updated content.

Let's say the original content is "123" and updated "12345" and hit update button.

```
$post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
```

it gets "123" only.

Did i missed something?

Comment: do you have any javascript errors?

Comment: no script error.

Answer (score 1):

> `$editor_id`
>       (string) (required) HTML id attribute value for the textarea and TinyMCE. (may only contain lower-case letters)
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

The second parameter passed to `wp_editor` needs to match the `id` attribute of the textarea, not the *`name`* attribute. Your textarea doesn't even have and `id` add one, then use that.

```
<textarea id="mypostcontent" name="post_content" rows="10"
```

Comment: that's the old one, and I didn't use id. but for wp-editor, I added id. $editor_id = 'editpost';
but it's not working.

Comment: Using the `id`, it works when I test it. There is something else interfering.